# next() selects not the correct element

Tags: jquery

I have a HTML list, which looks like this:

```
<ul class="search_list">
  <li class="header">Header1</li>
  <li class="item">Text1<li>
  <li class="item current">Text2<li>
  <li class="header">Header2</li>`
  <li class="item">Text3<li>
</ul>
```

I created a jQuery script which scrolls through the list of elements using the arrow keys. This works fine between the items `text1` and `text2`, but I want that even if `text2` is selected (marked with class current) and I press the arrow-down key that `text3` is selected, but this wouldn't work. But I don't understand it, because I use the following jQuery script and I explicitly ask for the class item... How can I solve this? I assume that the `class="header"` is the problem...

http://jsfiddle.net/sfDJs/7/

I just figured out, that it works like this. But is this fine coding? :)

`$('.search_list li.current').next().next('.search_list_item').addClass('current');`

Comment: You said you had it partially working, so can you update the jsfiddle to work? You need to select jQuery as the framework (look on the left), and your code should presumably be in some kind of keyup or keydown handler.

Comment: Just something: I'm not sure but I think it's not save to rely on key codes, because they are different with some keyboards. Eventually there is some other function you could use for that.

Comment: @nnnnnn: is this better? http://jsfiddle.net/sfDJs/7/

Answer (score 5):

`next` get immediately following sibling, if selector is provided, retrieves next sibling only if it matches that. In your case after one section of items next one sibling is `.header`, `$(".search_list_item .current").next('.item')` give you `.item` if next one element is exactly `.item`. 
`nextAll`, `prevAll` are performs the same thing with   difference - get all of  them next/prev siblings matching to selector.
Should be:

```
$(document).keydown( function(e){ 
    if (e.which == 40) {
        $('.search_list li.item:not(:last)').filter(".current").removeClass("current").nextAll(".item:first").addClass("current"); 
    } else if (e.which == 38) {
        $('.search_list li.item:not(:first)').filter(".current").removeClass('current').prevAll('.item:first').addClass("current")
      }
});
```

`:not(:first)`,`:not(:last)` - because  that is securing before going outside the menu.
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sfDJs/9/